# Bash on macOS, alt+d inserts ∂ instead of removing word

Tags: macos, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

After switching to MacOS I noticed the `alt+d` shortcut (delete word starting from the cursor position) doesn't work. It inserts `∂` character instead.

This has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12335787/12014002 with a suggestion to use another shortcut (`Esc than d`) or change the meta key which I don't want to do because it changes a few other things.

However, I'm using another Linux machine and have muscle memory for `alt+d` :) Since the other question is 8 years old maybe another solution popped up? The terminal app I'm using is Alacritty.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Update:

As of *Feb 2 2023*, Alacritty’s `option_as_alt` feature has [**finally been implemented,**](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/commit/1c878a0476257d328113efcd7088f1aa53f42e56) and the 6-yr-old issue’s been closed! 
You can now use `option_as_alt: (OnlyLeft|OnlyRight|Both|None)` in `alacritty.yml`.

---

##### TL;DR

The best solution I can think of, is to do what [this user did](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/62#issuecomment-347552058) to their **keymaps in `alacritty.yml`** — adding a bunch of key-maps that manually capture the **Option** (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) key for ***all* the bindings that you’d ever use meta for**.

---

This is something the Alacritty community has been ruminating about this macOS scenario for about **4.5 years**, at the time of writing of this answer (**see [issue#62](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/62)** that asks for an option to capture modifier keys that macOS uses differently — like **Option** (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) — for purposes e.g. serving as the meta key).

###### The Half-full Part

Turns out that the above ticket has been tagged as an `enhancement` — i.e., a plausible future feature — by the maintainers of Alacritty. One maintainer also uses the phrase *not **yet**  a feature*, when referring to the concept (see [this](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/1467#issuecomment-407206507) comment.)

There could be hope yet! Despite #62 having an over-four-year-long-yet-unresolved history, it is still alive and kicking.

---

**N.B.:** *Apple Terminal* has a built-in keyboard shortcut/menubar item (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> / Edit → Use Option as Meta Key). *`iterm`* also has a similar option. This may not be a viable option for the OP, but I’m just putting this here in case it helps a reader for whom it is.

Answer (score 1):

In Alacritty 0.12 you can configure the option key in your `alacritty.yml`

> Make `Option` key behave as `Alt` (macOS only):
>
> - OnlyLeft
> - OnlyRight
> - Both
> - None (default)

e.g.

```
window:
    option_as_alt: OnlyLeft
```